# Did the sort order of questions change?

Tags: bug, question-lists

I wonder if the order rule of newest question has changed.

I remember seeing questions in Newest is ordered by the ask time, but today in the [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) tag, the questions look very strange. There are questions asked two month ago on the second page and other questions are very old.

I refreshed many times. Did the order change or did I set something to make this happen?

> [image: second page]

> [image: third page]

Comment: Hrm, yeah, I see questions over a year old on the 2nd page. That's odd.

Comment: @AnnaLear you see that too?I have refresh so many times I thought it's my qustion.>>>>>_<<<<<<

Comment: The questions shown in the second page are out of order; in the third page, I see questions asked about 15 hours ago. Something is wrong. Should not this a bug report?

Comment: @kiamlaluno It is now. :P

Comment: look I found a bug

Comment: Something is up; I can't repro that, but there should be 40+ pages of this month alone. Pulling a copy locally, then I'll reset the system.

Comment: Resetting that part of the system has fixed the symptom, but I'll try to find what went wrong.

Comment: @MarcGravell hum…… not understand what's your word mean,but glad to see it's OK now.

Comment: @Winnie fair enough ;p But if you really want to know, we have a separate subsystem designed to handle "by tag / combination-of-tag" requests, that isn't the main RDBMS. Sometimes it gets confused.

Comment: @MarcGravell oh I see,so you can operate the Stack website,that's cool.

Comment: @Winnie, yes I'm part of the dev team here.

Comment: @MarcGravell hi are you here? it appear again.

Comment: @Winni a bit busy to look, buy I've sent a "reload" signal everywhere

Comment: @MarcGravell okay,Oh ,i think it crash now.

Comment: @Winnie how so?

Comment: @MarcGravell i think its appear again